# Vue 2; DOM not updating to data change and watcher

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a child component that gets passed a `initialCurrentUser` prop. This starts from the top parent `<App>` component, to a child `Sidebar`, and then finally to grandchild, `WindowFavorite`.

When the user is not logged in, the variable is `null`. When they are, it's an object with their properties including `favorites` which is an array of their favorited entries.

On the `<App>`, I have:

```
<template>
<sidebar
    :initial-current-user="currentUser">
    </sidebar>
</template>

...

export default {
    name: "App",
    ...
    data() {
        return {
            currentUser: null,
        };
    },
   methods: {
   ...
   getUser() { // sets this.currentUser on login success}
   }
```

In `<Sidebar>`, I'm setting a data prop to the `initialCurrentUser`, call `currentUser`, and passing that to the child `WindowFavorite`.

Then in the watcher on `Sidebar`, I have:

```
 initialCurrentUser: {
            handler: function( val ) {
                this.currentUser = val;
            },
            immediate: true
        }
```

The `<Sidebar>` DOM elements are reacting to this change. But when I pass to `<WindowFavorite>`, the loop in the DOM is checking for the `favorites` property on a `null` value. Even though the `currentUser` is  being updated (I see it updated in Vue Dev Tools), the DOM still thinks it's `null`.

```
template>
  <div>
    
        <div v-for="favorite in currentUser.favorites" :key="favorite.id" class="py-6 border-b border-brand-mint-muted-alt">
           

        </div>
      

 
  </div>
</template>

<script>


export default {
    name: "WindowFavorites",
    components: {
        
    },
    data() {
  
        return {
            currentUser: this.initialCurrentUser
        };
    },

    props: {
        initialCurrentUser: {
            default: null,
            type: Object
        }

    },
    
    mounted() {
 
    },
    watch: {
        initialCurrentUser: {
            handler: function( user ) {
                this.currentUser = user;
            }
        }
    },
    computed: {
     
    },
    methods: {

    }
};
</script>
```

So while the DOM thinks `currentUser` is null, it's actually:

```
{
"id":1,
"favorites":[ {id: 1}, { id: 2}]
}
```

I'm not sure why the DOM isn't being reactive.

To recap,  manages the initial change of `currentUser`. It's passed to `<Sidebar>`, which then passes that to `WindowFavorite`. `<Sidebar>` has a watcher to watch for the prop change and sets its own `currentUser` data var, and then uses that to pass to ITS child props.

The data seems to be updating throughout the components and shows correctly in the Vue Dev Tools, however, the dom itself still thinks the changing variable is null.

Once a page refresh happens, it grabs the data correctly. Just not on actual javacript data change.

Comment: Since user is an object, your watcher needs to have `deep: true` enabled: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<Sidebar>` and its `<WindowFavorites>` child are rendered immediately before `currentUser` is set in `App.vue`, and their `initialCurrentUser` props are both bound to `currentUser`, which is initially `null`. `WindowFavorites` tries to render its template, referring to `currentUser.favorites` (where `currentUser` is `null`), leading to the error you observed. Even though  `currentUser` is asynchronously updated afterward, the `null` reference has already occurred, blocking any updates.

One solution is to render `WindowFavorites` conditionally on `currentUser`:

```html
<!-- Sidebar.vue -->
<WindowFavorites v-if="currentUser" :initial-current-user="currentUser" />
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue2-conditional-rendering?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FSidebar.vue)